# How to call the Delete method in the controller using Blazor view In Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have created an **asp.net CRUD application** and implemented **blazor view** as it's view part
I have a list of values which i call from db and when i try to delete particaluar value or
when i delete initially it worked but the second time i try to delete its not even getting hit in the **delete method of the controller,only first time it will get hit in the controller** Everytime i close the application and click on delete it works but the second time it wont work it will show the webpage not found like this
**
This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:12344/Delete/027654fb-c35d-33e2-9730-0231d02af122
HTTP ERROR 404**

Please help me find a solution for this

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@inject System.Net.Http.HttpClient HttpClient

<h3>DesignationList</h3>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                NumericId
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Slug
            </th>
            <th>
                Status
            </th>
            <th>
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Designation)
        {
         <tr>
            <td>
            @item.NumericId
            </td>
            <td>
            @item.Name
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Slug
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Status
            </td>

            <td>

                <a href="Delete" asp-action="Delete" asp-route- 
               id="@item.Id" asp-controller="Designation">

            </td>
         </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
  @code {[Parameter] public IEnumerable<Global.Light.Time.Models.Designation> Designation { get; set; } }
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Izzy Added the code to the question,Thanks!

Comment: @Izzy I think the Id is not passed to the controller

Answer (score 0):

After check the code, I believe the except url should be

```
https://localhost:12344/Designation/Delete/027654fb-c35d-33e2-9730-0231d02af122
```

Not

```
https://localhost:12344/Delete/027654fb-c35d-33e2-9730-0231d02af122
```

And the easiest way to verify it is using the developer tools in browser, click the delete button and check the http request information under the Network tab. You can reproduce the issue and compare the difference between the normal one and the failed request.

[image]

After checking the code, I think you can use `LinkGenerator` to replace `asp-controller` and `asp-action`.

```
@page "/designation-list"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@inject System.Net.Http.HttpClient HttpClient
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.LinkGenerator LinkGenerator
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager NavigationManager

<h3>Designation List</h3>

@if (Designation == null)
{
    <p>Loading...</p>
}
else if (Designation.Any())
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>NumericId</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Slug</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Designation)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.NumericId</td>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Slug</td>
                    <td>@item.Status</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-link" @onclick="() => DeleteDesignation(item.Id)">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
else
{
    <p>No designation found.</p>
}

@code {
    private IEnumerable<Global.Light.Time.Models.Designation> Designation;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await LoadDesignation();
    }

    private async Task LoadDesignation()
    {
        Designation = await HttpClient.GetJsonAsync<IEnumerable<Global.Light.Time.Models.Designation>>("api/Designation");
    }

    private async Task DeleteDesignation(string id)
    {
        var response = await HttpClient.DeleteAsync($"api/Designation/{id}");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            await LoadDesignation();
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle deletion failure
        }
    }

    private string DeleteLink(string id)
    {
        var deleteUrl = LinkGenerator.GetUriByAction(HttpContext, action: "Delete", controller: "Designation", values: new { id });
        return deleteUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have fixed the error by <a href="Designation/Delete/@item.Id">Delete</a> Thank you for helping me

Comment: @Groot Glad to hear you have resolved the issue, could you accept my answer, it points using the wrong url.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the error by:

```html
  <a href="Designation/Delete/@item.Id">Delete</a>
```

Comment: edited your answer and anchor tag will be visible soon, once it does, please remove the PS.